# Threejs Renderer canvas does not fit assigned div

Tags: javascript, renderer, threejs-editor

I am trying to display a threejs scene inside nested div. Even changing renderer size, I keep having the canvas occupy too much space.

Initializing renderer:

```
// Init renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
antialias: true,
// canvas: document.getElementById("buildingDisplay")
})
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(document.getElementById("buildingDisplay").getBoundingClientRect().width, 
document.getElementById("buildingDisplay").getBoundingClientRect().height)
document.getElementById("buildingDisplay").appendChild(renderer.domElement)
```

The canvas containing the scene (in the 'buildingDispplay' div) has a size that fills the whole parent div.

HTML div structure:

```
<div id="parent" style="display:flex; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="blastMapID" style="height: 100%;">
        <button type="button" id="expTA" style="margin-top: 100px;"><strong>LoadTargetArea</strong></button>
    </div>
    <div id="buildingDetails" style="display:none;  width: 100%; height: 100%; border:1px solid black;">      
        <button id="closeDiv">Close</button>
        <div id="buildingDisplay" style="width: 100%; height: 60%; background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);">
            <!-- <canvas id="renderCanvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas> -->
        </div>
        <div id="statsDisplay" style="width: 100%; height: 40%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to limit the size of your canvas container with fixed pixels/value.

Comment: Curious thing is that setting the div "BuildingDisplay" to fixed size(max-height and max-width) makes the canvas stretch the window rightward and expands into it, leaving the "blastMapID" div intact

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to make it work like this:

Renderer in JS file:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
   antialias: true,
   canvas: document.getElementById("renderCanvas")
})
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="parent" style="display:flex; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="blastMapID" style="height: 100%;">
        <button type="button" id="expTA" style="margin-top: 100px;"><strong>LoadTargetArea</strong></button>
    </div>
    <div id="buildingDetails" style="display:none;  width: 100%; height: 100%; border:1px solid black;">      
        
        <div id="buildingDisplay" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 60%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            <canvas id="renderCanvas" style="max-width: 100%; max-height:600px;"></canvas>
            <button id="closeDiv">Close</button>
        </div>
        <div id="statsDisplay" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```